# imu and pid controller using rosserial

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is just a general question. I'm new to this so from what I understand so far, we can only make one node for one arduino. So it is either a listener or talker. So I'm wondering if it is possible to write a pid controller code which uses data from an IMU, and use the controller in some functions(a function that makes robot move forward, a function that makes the robot spin, etc) and have arduino listen to a command, and it chooses which function to use based on that command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200060/imu-and-pid-controller-using-rosserial/) by [cty11002](https://answers.ros.org/users/21236/cty11002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is totally possible but you are right about it being only one node.  However, rosserial can allow for multiple publishers (talkers) and subscribers (listeners) so it shouldn't be an issue.  The maximum depends on the actual micro-controller.  Are the IMU and controller on the Arduino?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cty11002](https://answers.ros.org/users/21236/cty11002/) on 2014-12-26**:
Thanks for answering. Yes, so IMU and four motors are connected to the Arduino and the controller is written in the sketch. But the Arduino doesn't need to publish IMU data, it only needs to listen to the command by user (or some decision making algorithm) and change motor speed based on the command

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-12-26**:
I've done something similar [here](https://github.com/tonybaltovski/ros_arduino) if you want to take a look.